# displaying a reversed array? java

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

It prints
Flip Method (only prints 9 to 5 ) but I want it to print from 9 to 0
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/g67v8.jpg
      public static void flip(int[] flp){
         System.out.println("This is the flip method");

```
     for ( int i = 0;  i < flp.length; i++){
     int e = flp.length-1;
     int temp = flp[e-i];
     flp[i] = flp[e-i];
     flp[i] = temp;
      e--;
     System.out.println("Index"+(i)+" :"+flp[i]); //is this the problem?

   }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a runable example

Comment: Please provide a coherent question.

Comment: http://imgur.com/gggiJwn         // this is with for ( int i = 0;  i <flp.length; i++)

Comment: You really shouldn't change the question once people start answering.  If you have a new question, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your logic to following to reverse the full array

```
 public static void flip(int[] flp){
 System.out.println("This is the flip method");
 for ( int i = 0;  i < flp.length/2; i++){
     int e = flp.length-(1+i);
     int temp = flp[i];
     flp[i] = flp[e];
     flp[e] = temp;
    // remove print from here. else you will get half of the array
    // since flp.length/2
   }
}
```

Add that in a separate method.

```
 for(int i = 0;  i < flp.length; i++){
   System.out.println("Index"+(i)+" :"+flp[i]);
 }
```

Comment: but when i do i < flp.length; it prints from 9 to 5, then 5 to 9

Comment: http://imgur.com/WxYvaFI //im still having the issue

Comment: @Codecka You have to change your first for loop to my one. Your reversing way is not correct.

Comment: i did the adjustments like yours it prints the array from 0 - 9... i want it to print from 9 to 0..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are printing half of the elements

```
i < flp.length/2
```

That should be

```
i < flp.length
```

Comment: +1, competing on time after a long time ;-) you won by 10 seconds.

Comment: but when i do i < flp.length; it prints from 9 to 5, then 5 to 9 :/

Comment: By changing `i < flp.length/2` will change the reversing logic. to print the array should use different for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop prints 9 to 5 because this is how you have configured your loop to iterate till `i < flp.length/2` .

Change it to:

```
i < flp.length
```

from

```
i < flp.length/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your for loop is fine - but you should remove the printing from inside that loop, and have it in a seperate loop after the flip loop

```
 for ( int i = 0;  i < flp.length; i++){
   System.out.println("Index"+(i)+" :"+flp[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void flip(int[] flp) {
    System.out.println("This is the flip method");

    int e = flp.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < flp.length / 2; i++) {

        int temp = flp[i];
        flp[i] = flp[e];
        flp[e] = temp;
        e--;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < flp.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Index" + (i) + " :" + flp[i]); 
    }
}
```